# STRIPE - Dynamically set amount returns null when called on charge.php

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to enable users to dynamically set the value of their donations through Stripe. I have been able to assign a value for 'amount' using a StripeAmount variable, but when I try to call this variable on my charge.php file, the variable returns null. I have search google endlessly for a solution but none work. I am a relative novice.

= Form Code =

```
        <form id="target_form" action="charge.php" method="POST">

        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

        <button class="stripe_button_style" id="myStripeButton">Give By Card</button>           

                <script>
                    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                        key: "pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        image: "includes/images/stripe_logo.png",
                        token: function(token, args){
                           var form = $('#target_form');
                            form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token.id));

                            form.get(0).submit();
                            }
                    });

                    document.getElementById('myStripeButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

                        var StripeAmount = $("#donation_amount").val() *100;

                        handler.open({
                            name: "company name",
                            description: "donation",
                            panelLabel: "Give:",
                            allowRememberMe: true,
                            amount: StripeAmount,
                            zipCode: true,
                            shippingAddress: true,
                            billingAddress: true
                        });
                          e.preventDefault();
                        });

                        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
                        handler.close();
                    });
                </script>

            </form>
```

= Charge.php Code =

```
<?php require_once('includes/stripe/init.php');
 $stripe = array(
  "secret_key"      => "sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "publishable_key" => "pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 );
  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
  $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
  $email = $_POST['stripeEmail'];
  try {
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    'email' => $_POST['stripeEmail'],
    'source'  => $token));
 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  'amount' => $amount,
  'customer' => $customer->id,
  'currency' => "usd",
  'description' => $email));
  echo 'Thank you for your donation. We will send you a receipt by    email for your tax records within 48hours';

   var_dump($charge);
 }catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e){

echo $e->getMessage();

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your server-side code, `$amount` is never initialized.

Also, please note that the amount and currency passed to [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) are used for display purposes. Checkout will not send the amount and currency to the server.

You'd need to do something like this:

1. Update your client-side code to send the amount to the server:

   ```
   token: function(token, args) {
       var form = $('#target_form');
       form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="amount" />').val($("#donation_amount").val() * 100;));
       form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token.id));
       form.get(0).submit();
   }
   ```
2. Retrieve the amount in your server-side code:

   ```
   $amount = $_POST['amount'];
   ```

Comment: I needed to make one small edit, but otherwise this was perfect. Massive thanks.